# User select the filter criteria current_salary_range is 20000. I will show the results also salary range below 20000

Tags: views

I have created the content type named candidate_profile, included fields like Current_Salary_Range.

I have created a view and also I am using [better exposed filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) for current_salary_range field.

My  question is: When the user selects the filter criteria current_salary_range of 20000, I want to show the results who is having current_salary_range 20000 and also who is having current salary range below 20000.

how to proceed with this...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Content type Manage Fields, what you need to do is make the Current_Salary_Range **FIELD TYPE** be a (number) **Integer** field and not a text field.

> **Note:** You will have to delete and create a new field, as you cannot change field type after the field has been created

Then when you add it as a filter in your view, you should get the option of **less than or equal to**

[image]

**Note:** picture is from Drupal 8, but should be the same in Drupal 7.

Comment: i want to display both results who is having current_salary_range 20000 and below 20000.

Comment: Thanks Bro.  i am filter the result based on the salary range . i will check the no of results. if result is lesser-than 20 i will display salary range below given range(below 20000). and then i will check this result. if is it lesser-than 30. i will display results salary range greater-than 20000.